# Failed to find 'spark-submit2.cmd'

Tags: r, apache-spark, r-package

```
> library('BBmisc')
> library('sparklyr')
> sc <- spark_connect(master = 'local')
Error in start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, spark_version = version,  : 
  Failed to find 'spark-submit2.cmd' under 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\spark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7', please verify - SPARK_HOME.
> spark_home_dir()
[1] "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7"
> spark_installed_versions()
  spark hadoop                                                              dir
1 3.0.0    2.7 C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7
> spark_home_set()
Setting SPARK_HOME environment variable to C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local/spark/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7
> sc <- spark_connect(master = 'local')
Error in start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, spark_version = version,  : 
  Failed to find 'spark-submit2.cmd' under 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\spark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7', please verify - SPARK_HOME.
```

source : https://github.com/englianhu/binary.com-interview-question/issues/1#issue-733943885

May I know how to how to solve `Failed to find 'spark-submit2.cmd' under 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\spark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7', please verify - SPARK_HOME.`?

Reference : [Need help getting started with Spark and sparklyr](https://community.rstudio.com/t/need-help-getting-started-with-spark-and-sparklyr/22910)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved !!!**

Step :

1. https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html
2. extract zipped file to `'C:/Users/scibr/AppData/Local/spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2'`.
3. manually choose latest version : `spark_home_set('C:/Users/scibr/AppData/Local/spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2')`

GitHub source : https://github.com/englianhu/binary.com-interview-question/issues/1#event-3968919946